# how to know which extension or service of vscode editor consuming my internet data regularly?

Tags: visual-studio-code

how to know which extension or service of vscode editor consuming my internet data regularly?

I have already turned off `Telemetry` option in vscode editor settings but still vscode consuming high bandwidth of internet data.

I am using VS Code Editor Version: 1.64.1 (Universal) in mac.

BTW I am getting the same issue in Windows 10 also on my computer.

Is anyone getting same issue? If you have solved this issue, kindly suggest me to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have disabled all the extensions and restarted vs code editor but still getting same issue.

Comment: I blocked VsCode within Firewall, until issue is fixed, Would unblock when needed and then block again